# my member profile page not showing result?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my member profile page where I want the details of user to come ... but everything is getting printed including user id... but not the user record... I am new to this php and will appreciate any one help. screen shot is http://postimg.com/image/146000/screenshot-145081.jpg

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
    header("location:login.php");
} else {
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>! <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h2>
<table width="1105" height="140" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
  <th colspan="12">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="7"><?php if(isset($_GET["msg"])) echo $_GET["msg"];?></th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Company Name</td>
      <td>Mobile no.</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>City</td>
      <td>State</td>
      <td>Country</td>
      <td>Category</td>
      <td>Registration</td>
      <td>DOJ</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>

    <?php
  require("includes/connections.php");//to make connection with database
  $id=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
  $sql="select * from stonemember where id='$id'";//select query from table stonemember
  $result=mysql_query($sql);//result of select query in $result varialble
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["Name"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["CompanyName"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["mobileno"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["email"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["city"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["state"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["Country"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["cat"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["registered"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["Date"];?></td>
      <td><a href="admin/edit.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"];?>"Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
  }
  ?>

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: column names may be wrong. What do you mean user record not showing? Showed result does not belong the user?

Comment: show the column names of stonemember

Comment: Quentin, how can you know that the value of `$_SESSION["sess_user"]` is coming from user input?

Comment: $sql="insert into stonemember (Name, CompanyName, Businesstype, Officeno, mobileno, faxno, email, add1, add2, city, zip, state, Country, Sub, cat, discription, username, pass, registered, Date) 
VALUES ('$Name', '$CompanyName', '$Businesstype', '$Officeno', '$mobileno', '$faxno', '$email', '$add1', '$add2', '$city', '$zip', '$state', '$Country', '$Sub', '$cat', '$discription', '$username', '$pass', '$registered', now())";

Comment: Do you get any errors? Already tried debugging your code in any way? Check if and what your query returns. `var_dump()`

Comment: user details are not printing.. where as i am able to login with userid

Comment: This website has too many haters. First they downvote, then they complain about the code a lot. WHY? Just guide the man on his problem. We ALL have been in his place. @user3324146: where is the screenshot?

Comment: website is not allowing me to post image:(

Comment: for example, use [http://postimg.com/](http://postimg.com/). and please post the image in the original post.

Comment: http://postimg.com/image/146000/screenshot-145081.jpg

Comment: Try and run the query in phpmyadmin and see what results do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to learn to debug your scripts. Use google, others may have had the same problems.

**1. In your php script, before everything, use:**

```
erorr_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

usually, this will show ALL your script errors.

**2. Instead of:**

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

use

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

this way, if you get a mysql error, it will stop the script and show the error.

**3. Learn to use [var_dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).**

Example: after this part

```
$id=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
```

put this code:

```
var_dump($id);
```

this will show you if there is a value in $id variable and its type

Comment: var_dump($id); is giving this result string(1) "7"

after that i have replaces sess_user with id

Comment: Did you find the problem? If not, print the sql after `$sql="select * from stonemember where id='$id'";`, like this `print_r($sql);`, and use that sql string in phpmyadmin to see what are the results.

Comment: yeah with id it happened... thanks for your effort.  i m new to php and my concepts are not clear still i look code and try.  thanks.. one more thing what to use to print user name instead of this <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>

Comment: There is no specific method or good method vs bad method. You can store the username in the session, its fine.